# Is it exploitation at the workplace?

Tags: careers

I am currently working in a Biotech Company in France. It is a start-up and consists of 10 people. I joined 10 months back and got to know there are different types of tasks as the company is still evolving. I happily carried out the tasks and liked the diversity. However, initially, it was a lot of scientific work including some grant applications. After the work was done they said that they want me to work with marketing. That I also carried. Then they said I would be suitable as a Project manager. I worked as a Project manager and now they want me to write papers for them. However, I realized after working and finishing the writing of the papers, they said I only worked as a 'writer' and thus, I will not be part of the project any further. As I come from academia, I think when somebody works and writes a manuscript that person can claim the first author of the publication. Here, the situation is something else and I feet this is a passive way of exploitation and taking the chances of my flexibility. I would be happy carrying out the tasks, however, in return I expect the credit that I deserve. It seems they need a lot of scientists at this moment as there is a lot of scientific work. The names of different positions like Project Manager, Marketing Manager, etc are just created to deny the credits of the scientists. I am very upset and your suggestions regarding what I should do would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if writing the paper (as opposed to doing the research) should grant you first-authorship?

Comment: Could you please re-phrase your question?

Comment: You're saying you're "very upset" - why is that? Is that because you thought you would be first author on a paper when you wrote it (but someone did the experimental work)? Was there any agreement that a Project Manager would be first author on the paper? Most products in most industries do not have the developers' names on them in any way. I'm not sure which part is "exploitation" - you get paid, do you not?

Comment: There was no experimental part. It was a theoretical work and I worked 90% of it. But finally, the manager and one other person got the first authorship.

Answer (score 5):

The business world is not like academia.

Generally ideas like "first-authorship" don't exist.  The work that you do for the company belongs to the company.  Your name may get attached as a contact person, but that is the extent of "ownership".

You should make sure that your manager/supervisor is aware of your contributions and understands the value that your work provides.  Companies pay and promote based on your value to the company which is not likely measured in papers authored.

Titles at work are whatever the company makes of them.  I think you should be concerned more with the projects you are asked to work on than the titles applied.  Especially in a small startup, people need to do whatever needs getting done

Comment: I think that the concept of “first authorship” could exist, if the paper is being published in a journal that follows academic norms (e.g. rather than being self-published as a white paper).

Answer (score 0):

Are they exploiting you? Of course they are. Every employee is being exploited by their employer. They exploit your skill and knowledge in exchange for paying you money. There's nothing inherently wrong, immoral, unethical, or illegal with this relationship.

What you produce for your employer, in the majority of scenarios, belongs to your employer. They've paid you to perform tasks. What is produced from those tasks is for your employers benefit and belongs to your employer, not you. They owe you nothing more than what is legally required in your country.

Comment: Actually, copyright-law is a little bit more complicated in the EU at least ...

Comment: I wouldn't say being paid a fair wage for work is "being exploited", and I'd also say exploiting people is generally unethical.

Comment: Exploit; Make full use of and derive benefit from. - https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/exploit